# How to fetch and read a JSON file located on server?

Tags: java, android

I have a simple json file located on server path "myserver/samplejsontotest.json"

content of a json file is:

```
{"apps": [{"appName": "App1", "version": 1.0}, {"appName": "App2", "version": 4.6}]}
```

I want to load the json file, parse and read it's content and show App names when I click a button on Main activity. Below is my code in MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String path = "myserver/samplejsontotest.json";
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(path);

public MainActivity() throws JSONException {
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

           // Log.d("Button1", "Clicked on Button1");
        }

    });
}

public void parseJson() throws JSONException {

    JSONObject sys  = reader.getJSONObject("apps");
    String app = sys.getString("appName");
    String version = sys.getString("version");
}

}
```

Please help.

Comment: `new JSONObject(path);` ??? One cannot make a json object of a path. Let it be an invalid path. If the json file is on a server you should download it first. What is `myserver` ?

Comment: It seems you did not google for downloading and parsing a json file. All pretty standard. Or just read some pages here.

Comment: @greenapps, Thanks for your valuable answer. please suggest me how to download then and how to proceed further.

Comment: @greenapps, "myserver/samplejsontotest.json" this is the path pointing to server where json file is stored.

Comment: You already said that before. I can read. Why repeat it? Better tell what 'myserver' actually stands for.

Comment: where is the server seating, are you going to connect to it via internet, if internet is it via http or ftp, so many unclear things with your question.

Comment: "http://servername/myserver/samplejsontotest.json" this is the actual server parth. I am going to connect it via internet via http.

Comment: ok, you told us what you want. Now tell us what is the problem. Why you can't do what you want?

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko, I am new to android, I searched on internet regarding how to load and parse json data and I tried it but it cold not work that's why I asked here expected to get some help. Actually I am not getting the proper way to do this

Comment: split your questions into parts: 1) how to load json from the internet (same way as any other text). 2) how to parse json. Now solve them one by one. You can find answers for both of them on the internet

Comment: I'm voting to close this question considering OP put in **no** effort, is guessing random code in his project, does not read documentation **and** is asking for tools which is off-topic.

Answer (score -2):

Try the Rest Template of Spring.

Just create a java class that represents the json structure, and consume the json file as a GET method.

Reference:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-android/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/html/rest-template.html

Comment: Any reason to use this over any other well known and reliable library?

Comment: While it is possible to use Spring with Android, I don't think this is a helpful suggestion for someone who is apparently struggling with the basics of Android.